# How do I know if my result is statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design

I wanted to test the effectiveness of 3 different messages I sent to users(respondents) to take a survey. In total, I sent out 6000 messages (3 sets of 2000 users). For message A, I received a response rate of 16.5%, or 330 users response. For message B, I received a response rate of 18.1%, or 362 users response. For message C, I received a response rate of 18.9%, or 378 users response. I would like to conclude message C would garner the best response rate in future but how can I tell if my results are statistically significant? What are the ingredients that I need for future tests?

Comment: Are the message categories A,B,C ordered?

Comment: @Glen_b, they are not ordered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can address the problem as a test of homogeneity, in which you are extending the z-test of proportions between two groups. Your data (`survey`) can be tabulated as follows:

```
        Message
Response    A    B    C  Sum
     Yes  330  362  378 1070
     No  1670 1638 1622 4930
     Sum 2000 2000 2000 6000
```

In a test of homogeneity the margins are considered as random variables, and the expected cell values obtained by cross-multiplying the margins.

A $\chi^2$-test is performed. In R it would be as follows:

```
chisq.test(survey)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  survey
X-squared = 4.0765, df = 2, p-value = 0.1303
```

showing a p value that is above the generally considered acceptable risk to reject the null hypothesis - it does not seem as though the differences in response rate between messages are statistically significant.

Comment: Thanks @Antoni Paradella. btw, I found more info here for anyone else dropping by
http://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/homogeneity.aspx?Tutorial=AP